# NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "the network connection was lost."

Tags: ios, web-services

Basically this question asked multiple time but in my point, I can't able to clear out those so I want your side help for this error.

My app was `complete` with all decided features but it was giving me following `error multiple time in log`.

[image]

App is totally `custom web server` based and I was using `GoDaddy server` for placing `admin panel content` and for webservices.

In all loading pages , app has to call different web services. In this its work normally with good response but some time it will take so much `time in loading page details` and I got above kind of `error log in XCode.`

If next time, I call same service then its respond me quickly but some time, it creating problem for me.

From coding side, I am very much sure its just delay in server response because process become stuck in waiting of server response.

Comment: are your webservices https based ?

Comment: Yes I was using web services but not https based, its normal http request.

Comment: when such error occurrs did you check your webservice response , is there any response or not ?\

Comment: Yes @ShobhakarTiwari there is response from server after some sort of waiting (loading...), that I have given in above image. There is fail response.

Comment: then just ignore it

Comment: Is it possible that I have opened cPanel within browser and then try to access web services and I was getting these errors. Because on same IP address two sessions firing requests.

Comment: As per my thinking, If I close cPanel window then I was not getting this kind of error but not sure actually about this. I can't ignore this error because delay time is noticeable large.

Comment: yea quite possible